# Unable to use firebase admin sdk in google cloud run application

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-run, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to use the firebase admin sdk in my javascript web application hosted in google cloud run so that I can manage firebase users. It is working locally but not on google cloud.

I was able to get this working successfully on my local machine by using the firebase-admin library, and initializing an app as follows:

```
export default admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG)
})
```

In this case, I point the cert to the json file that I downloaded directly from firebase. This works locally, but when I try to replicate it in google cloud run, I am not able to. For reference, in cloud run, I store this json file as a secret, but when I build and deploy the app, it won't actually start up and run on the port (this is never an issue without this code so that implies the firebase code is the issue). When I log out the env variable (secret), it looks exactly as it's supposed to.

Since this was not working, I took a different approach of using the google application default credentials when not local (as recommended by google's docs). In this case, I made my logic conditional so when I'm not local I would use the following:

```
export default admin.initializeApp()
```

This allowed me to get past the build and deploy error, but when I run the code to actually interact with firebase, it spits back an error. I have taken many steps to ensure that all relevant firebase management and identity APIs are enabled in my gcp environment, provided the service account cloud run is using with access to the firebase admin sdk, and every other option that I could see online. I also tried specifying initialize app to use the default credentials and providing a database which I saw referenced in some answers.

At the end of the day, I keep getting the same error:

> FirebaseAuthError: There is no configuration corresponding to the provided identifier.

I am pretty stuck at the moment, and have sank many, many hours into troubleshooting this. Does anyone have any suggestions of how I can remedy these issues, whether it's using explicit credentials or default ones? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this issue was being caused by the formatting of the private_key property, as it contained '\n' in a few places which was not being interpreted correctly. The fix was to split up the json object and apply the following logic to the private_key:

```
private_key: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.split(
        String.raw`\n`
).join("\n")
```